# How to implement python dictionaries into code to do the same job as list functions

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to be able to implement dictionaries into this code. Not all needs to be changed just were i can change it and it still does the same job.

In a test file I have a list of three strings (1, once),(2,twice).(2, twice).

I'm guessing the number will represent the value.
This code passes the tests but I am struggling to understand how I can use dictionaries to make it do the same job.

If any one can help it'll be grateful.

The current  is:

The list items are in a test file elsewhere.

```
class Bag:

    def __init__(self):
        """Create a new empty bag."""
        self.items = []

    def add(self, item):
        """Add one copy of item to the bag. Multiple copies are allowed."""
        self.items.append(item)

    def count(self, item):
        """Return the number of copies of item in the bag.

        Return zero if the item doesn't occur in the bag.
        """
        counter = 0
        for an_item in self.items:
            if an_item == item:
                counter += 1
        return counter

    def clear(self, item):
        """Remove all copies of item from the bag. 

        Do nothing if the item doesn't occur in the bag.
        """
        index = 0
        while index < len(self.items):
            if self.items[index] == item:
                self.items.pop(index)
            else:
                index += 1

    def size(self):
        """Return the total number of copies of all items in the bag."""
        return len(self.items)

    def ordered(self):
        """Return the items by decreasing number of copies.

        Return a list of (count, item) pairs.
        """
        result = set()
        for item in self.items:
            result.add((self.count(item), item))
        return sorted(result, reverse=True)
```

I have been scratching my head over it for a while now. I can only use these also for dictionaries.

```
Items[key] = value 
len(items)
dict() 
items[key] 
key in items
Del items[key]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest possible problem. You have an empty bag:

```
self.items = {}
```

and now a caller is trying to add an item, with `bag.add('twice')`.
Where shall we put the item?
Well, we're going to need some unique index.
Hmmm, different every time, different every time, what changes with each `.add()`?
Right, that's it, use the length!

```
n = len(self.items)
self.items[n] = new_item
```

So `items[0] = 'twice'`.
Now, does this still work after a 2nd call?
Yes. `items[1] = 'twice'`.

Following this approach you should be able to refactor the other methods to use the new scheme.
Use unit tests, or debug statements like `print('after clear() items is: ', self.items)`, to help you figure out if the Right Thing happened.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It makes sense now. Would I still be able to implement any more into the code that uses dictionaries? Again thank you mate